# Debugging arbitrary ARM binary image using IDA and QEMU

Tags: ida, arm, qemu

i'm new to this and still learning a lot. Now i have managed to download the binary image from an Flash memory out of a unit having an OMAP5912 SoC. The SoC has an ARM9 family CPU core running little endian ARM code.
For now i could disassemble it using IDA Pro, but some things need to be checked at runtime.
Therefore i was looking for a way to execute instructions step-by-step, watching the registers, set breakpoints and such.
My binary has no symbols inside.
Is is possible to let QEMU emulate the CPU using "qemu-sytem-arm" and connect this to IDA Pro debugger?
If so, please help me in that, because i'm new to debugging.

Comment: You can go through the related questions on the right for some insights.